# Genie's private constructor

Tags: constructor, private, genie

This small piece of Vala code, I read it from [rosettacode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Singleton#Vala)

```
public class Singleton : Object {
    static Singleton? instance;

    Singleton() { }  // Private constructor

    public static Singleton get_instance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Singleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Vala:

```
var a = new Singleton ();
```

will output error

> error: Access to private member `Singleton.new' denied

How to do that in Genie? A **private constructor**?

How to translate this line to Genie?

```
Singleton() { }  // Private constructor
```

Comment: `var a = Singleton.get_instance();`

Comment: Thanks, I know that. my question is How to do that in Genie? When `var a = new Singleton`. output same error.